# Identify columns causing duplicates

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that gets loaded with data. It SHOULD NOT contain duplicate ID's, but it is not a perfect world, people make errors and duplicates occure. My table looks like this, but with many, MANY more columns:

```
ID    col_a    col_b    col_c    col_d
1     1        d        f        e    
2     r        g        v        s  
2     r        s        v        s
3     dd       ee       tt       ww
3     rf       DD       tt       ww
3     dd       DD       tt       ww
3     rf       ee       tt       ww
4     a        a        a        a
```

as you can see cloumn col_b causes a duplicate for ID = 2 and col_a and col_b causes duplicates for ID = 3. I can identify the ID's with duplicate rows with a simple query like this:

```
select * from (select ID,  count row from TABLE  group by ID) where ROW > 1;
```

this will return something like:

```
ID    ROW
2     2
3     4
```

but what would REALLY help me is a query that would return something like this:

```
ID    col_a    col_b    col_c    col_d    ROW
2              TRUE                       2
3     TRUE     TRUE                       4
```

...or any OTHER solution that would highlight not only the duplicated ID's but also the columns which are causing them.

Oh, I am using DB2.

Comment: If `ID` should be unique, then why isn't it defined with a unique constraint or as the primary key?

Comment: as I mentioned... it's not a perfect world and people make errors ... and other people.. in this case me :) have to deal with those errors

Comment: the order of records in a table needs to be defined. how are you determining that the 2nd row for (3) is rf. recrods inserted to a table doesnt have to be the order. Do you have any other column to fixate the order of records within an id

Comment: That's why you should define the column as unique - to prevent the errors

Comment: Guys, I totally understand what SHOULD HAVE been done. and in fact I absolutelly agree with you. But this is a case where we are given data from the client and told to "just deal with it". I have no control over the source data nor am I in a position to give any feedback that would change things. It's basically "just make it work"

Comment: What kind of output you want to show the column causing duplicate? Please give the sample output just like you gave for duplicate ID.

Comment: @SureshGajera , I did. at the end of my post I show the output that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id
       , case when c_a = 1 then null else 'True' end COL_A
       , case when c_b = 1 then null else 'True' end COL_B
       , case when c_c = 1 then null else 'True' end COL_C
       , case when c_d = 1 then null else 'True' end COL_D
       , c ROW
from (select id
            , count(distinct col_a) c_a
            , count(distinct col_b) c_b
            , count(distinct col_c) c_c
            , count(distinct col_d) c_d
            , count(*) c
      from test
      group by id)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=dc6796fc64bc70446add525444c7a4bd)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ID 
        ,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col_a) >1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE '' END AS Col_a
        ,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col_b) >1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE '' END AS Col_b
        ,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col_c) >1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE '' END AS Col_c
        ,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col_d) >1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE '' END AS Col_d  
        ,COUNT(1) AS [Row]
FROM      #Table
GROUP BY  ID
HAVING    COUNT(1)>1
ORDER BY  ID
```